# Which integers, satisfying a condition, satisfy the equation $a^2+b^2+16c^2=9k^2+1$

Tags: calculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, functions, contest-math

I found the following question, on a past international competition:

Find all prime numbers $a, b, c$ and all positive integers k, which satisfy the equation: $a^2+b^2+16c^2=9k^2+1$

I solved it with the following laborious and tedious method:

$a^2+b^2+c^2mod3\equiv 1$

However $x^2\equiv 0 or 1 mod3$, for all integers x.

So we have that either $a\equiv b\equiv 0mod3$, $c\equiv 1or2mod3$ or any of its permutations hold true.

If $a\equiv bmod3$

Then $a=3$, $b=3$

Then $18+16c^2=9k^2+1$

$17+16c^2=9k^2$

I create a function $f$, such that $f(x)=x^2-(x-1)^2$

$f'(x)=2$

So $f$ is increasing and 1-1.

For $c>2$ (from the above) we have that $16c^2+17$ can't be a square of an integer, since $16^2$ is a square and hence since for c>2, $(4c+1)^2-16c^2>17$, which is true from the $f$ function created above. So we have that $c=2$ is the only solution, with $c=2, a=3, b=3, k=3$.

If $a\equiv c\equiv 0mod3$, $b\equiv 1or2mod3$

$a=c=3$

So $9+b^2+16*9=9k^2+1$

$b^2+153=9k^2+1$

$b^2+152=9k^2$

So we have $b^2+152\equiv 0mod9$

So $b\equiv 1 or 8 mod9$

If $x=81$, then $f(x)=81^2-80^2=161>152$, so from the conclusions we derived earlier on about the function $f$, we have that b<80.

Now we break it up into sub-parts:

$b=1$: $153=9k^2$ false

$b=8$: $216=9k^2$ false

$b=10$: $252=9k^2$ false

$b=17$: $441=9k^2$

So $k=7$

$b=19$: $513=9k^2$ false

$b=26$: $828=9k^2$ false

$b=28$: $936=9k^2$ false

$b=35$: $1377=9k^2$ false

$b=37$: $1521=9k^2$

$k=13$

$b=44$: $2088=9k^2$ false

$b=46$: $2268=9k^2$ false

$b=53$: $3113=9k^2$ false

$b=55$: $3177=9k^2$ false

$b=62$: $3996=9k^2$ false

$b=64$: $4248=9k^2$ false

$b=71:$ $5193=9k^2$ false

$b=73$: $5481=9k^2$ false

So from these sub-parts we have the following solutions:

$b=17, a=3, c=3, k=7$

$b=37, a=3, c=3, k=13$

If $b\equiv c\equiv 0mod3$, $a\equiv 1or2mod3$

Then it is symmetrical to the previous case:

So the solutions are:

$a=17, b=3, c=3, k=7$

$a=37, b=3, c=3, k=13$

So in total we have the following solutions:

$a=17, b=3, c=3, k=7$

$a=37, b=3, c=3, k=13$

$b=17, a=3, c=3, k=7$

$b=37, a=3, c=3, k=13$

$c=2, a=3, b=3, k=3$

My solution to the question is extremely long and tedious. Are there better approaches to the question? And if so could you please post them up?

Comment: oh sorry, thanks for picking me up on it, correcting it now

Comment: I'm lost at the beginning.  From $a^2+b^+c^2\equiv1\pmod3$ you conclude that two of $a,b,c\equiv0$ and the other $\equiv2$  Why shouldn't the third one be $\equiv1\pmod3$?

Comment: Sorry, you are indeed right, I checked my work many times, but for some reason I didn't see that, correcting it now. I must be tired :)

Comment: changed it, fortunately, I hadn't used the $b\equiv 2mod3$ later on

Comment: So I think it should be fine now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the OP observes, $a^2+b^2+16c^2=9k^2+1$ implies $a^2+b^2+c^2\equiv1$ mod $3$, which in turn implies either $a=b=3\not=c$ or, without loss of generality, $a\not=3=b=c$ (since $a$ and $b$ are interchangeable).

In the first case, we can rewrite the equation as $17=9k^2-16c^2=(3k+4c)(3k-4c)$, which implies $3k+4c=17$ and $3k-4c=1$, leading to $c=2$. So $3^2+3^2+16\cdot2^2=82=9\cdot3^2+1$ is a solution.

In the second case, we can rewrite the equation as $152=9k^2-a^2=(3k+a)(3k-a)$. We need to find a factorization $152=mn$ such that $6\mid(m+n)$.  This requires $m$ and $n$ to both be even, which means one is divisible by $2$ and the other by $4$ (since $152=8\cdot19$), which limits us to $2\cdot76$ and $4\cdot38$, from which we get $a=(72-2)/2=37$ and $a=(38-4)/2=17$, respectively. Thus $37^2+3^2+16\cdot3^2=9\cdot13^2+1$ and $17^2+3^2+16\cdot3^2=9\cdot7^2+1$ are two more solutions, and (aside from swapping $a$ and $b$) that's the end of it.